# Is there a data view for MobileConnect in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, data-views

Similar to what we have for emails using _subscribers would there be one for MobileConnect?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few different Data Views that are associated with Mobile Connect:

- **_MobileAddress** (similar to Subscribers - **not officially supported**)
- **_MobileSubscription** (**no longer supported** - use _SMSSubscriptionLog instead)
- **_SMSSubscriptionLog** (stores subscription info for each Mobile Number)
- **_SMSMessageTracking** (message tracking information)

The one you are probably looking for is `_MobileAddress`.

Below is the info I can find around it:

```
_MobileAddress

 Field Name          Data Type   Required    Data     Default
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 _ContactID          Text                    Y                                
 _MobileNumber       Text(15)                Y                                
 _Status             Text                    N                                
 _Source             Text                    N                                
 _SourceObjectId     Text(200)               N                                
 _Priority           Text                    N        1
 _Channel            Text(20)                N                                
 _CarrierID          Text                    Y        0
 _CountryCode        Text(2)                 Y                                
 _CreatedDate        Date                    Y        GETDATE()    
 _CreatedBy          Text                    N                                
 _ModifiedDate       Date                    Y        GETDATE()    
 _ModifiedBy         Text                    N                                
 _City               Text(200)               N                                
 _State              Text(200)               N                                
 _ZipCode            Text(20)                N                                
 _FirstName          Text(100)               N                                
 _LastName           Text(100)               N                                
 _UTCOffset          Decimal(4,2)            N        0
 _IsHonorDST         Boolean                 N        false
```

For more detailed information please check out **[Zuzanna's DataView Article here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/)**, or **[Mateusz Dabrowski's article here](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views/#mobileconnect-data-views)**.

Both have TONS of great insight and information on these data views as well as others.

**As a final note** Please remember `_MobileAddress` is NOT officially supported, so it is 'use at your own risk'. So depending on this for production or repeatable processes come with a high risk of failure with no support or alternatives to cover any interruptions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, really appreciate it.